# eclipse - ternary formatting still broken?

Tags: eclipse, autoformatting

Eclipse

- Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
- Build id: 20200615-1200

Here's how my ternary operator formatting looks in the settings (which is how I want)...

[image]

I have set it to wrap every element on a new line.

Sometimes auto save puts everything on one line. Sometimes the first element is new line with single indentation, second element on new line but with 2 indents.

I've noticed other seemingly random behaviour where the subsequent statement gets horribly indented!

Are there other settings which affect this particular formatting or is this a bug?

Here's a screenshot of some code after autosaving (which triggers the auto-format)

Here's the exported formatter (with boilerplate removed so will fit)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<profiles version="19">
<profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="normal" version="19">
insert_space_after_ellipsis" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_enum_declarations" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_at_in_annotation_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_for_statment" value="common_lines"/>
comment.new_lines_at_block_boundaries" value="true"/>
insert_space_after_logical_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_constructor_declaration_parameters" value="insert"/>
comment.insert_new_line_for_parameter" value="do not insert"/>
insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_package" value="insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_method_invocation" value="common_lines"/>
insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
blank_lines_after_imports" value="1"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_while" value="do not insert"/>
comment.insert_new_line_before_root_tags" value="insert"/>
insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_annotation_type_member_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_record_declaration" value="common_lines"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_method_declaration_throws" value="do not insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_switch_statement" value="common_lines"/>
comment.format_javadoc_comments" value="true"/>
indentation.size" value="4"/>
insert_space_after_postfix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_enum_constant_declaration" value="common_lines"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_for_increments" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_type_arguments" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_arrow_in_switch_default" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_for_inits" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_semicolon_in_for" value="insert"/>
align_with_spaces" value="false"/>
disabling_tag" value="@formatter:off"/>
continuation_indentation" value="2"/>
number_of_blank_lines_before_code_block" value="0"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_switch_case_expressions" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_enum_constants" value="16"/>
blank_lines_before_imports" value="1"/>
number_of_blank_lines_at_end_of_method_body" value="0"/>
blank_lines_after_package" value="1"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_multiple_local_declarations" value="insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_if_while_statement" value="common_lines"/>
alignment_for_arguments_in_enum_constant" value="16"/>
insert_space_after_opening_angle_bracket_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
comment.indent_root_tags" value="false"/>
wrap_before_or_operator_multicatch" value="true"/>
enabling_tag" value="@formatter:on"/>
insert_space_after_closing_brace_in_block" value="insert"/>
comment.count_line_length_from_starting_position" value="true"/>
alignment_for_record_components" value="16"/>
insert_space_before_parenthesized_expression_in_return" value="insert"/>
alignment_for_throws_clause_in_method_declaration" value="16"/>
insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_parameter" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_arrow_in_switch_case" value="insert"/>
wrap_before_multiplicative_operator" value="true"/>
keep_then_statement_on_same_line" value="false"/>
insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_field" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_explicitconstructorcall_arguments" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_prefix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
blank_lines_between_type_declarations" value="1"/>
insert_space_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_for" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_catch" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_method" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_switch" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_parameterized_type_references" value="0"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_anonymous_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
alignment_for_logical_operator" value="16"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_parenthesized_expression" value="do not insert"/>
keep_annotation_declaration_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_record_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_enum_constant" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_multiplicative_operator" value="insert"/>
never_indent_line_comments_on_first_column" value="false"/>
insert_space_after_and_in_type_parameter" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_for_inits" value="insert"/>
indent_statements_compare_to_block" value="true"/>
brace_position_for_anonymous_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
insert_space_before_question_in_wildcard" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_method_invocation_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_switch" value="insert"/>
comment.align_tags_descriptions_grouped" value="true"/>
comment.line_length" value="80"/>
use_on_off_tags" value="false"/>
keep_method_body_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_between_empty_brackets_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
keep_loop_body_block_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_enum_constant" value="insert"/>
insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_assignment_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_for" value="do not insert"/>
comment.preserve_white_space_between_code_and_line_comments" value="false"/>
insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_local_variable" value="insert"/>
brace_position_for_method_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
blank_lines_before_abstract_method" value="1"/>
keep_enum_constant_declaration_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
align_variable_declarations_on_columns" value="false"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_union_type_in_multicatch" value="16"/>
insert_space_after_colon_in_for" value="insert"/>
keep_type_declaration_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
number_of_blank_lines_at_beginning_of_method_body" value="0"/>
insert_space_after_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
keep_else_statement_on_same_line" value="false"/>
parentheses_positions_in_catch_clause" value="common_lines"/>
alignment_for_additive_operator" value="16"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_multiple_field_declarations" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_record_constructor" value="insert"/>
alignment_for_arguments_in_explicit_constructor_call" value="16"/>
insert_space_before_relational_operator" value="insert"/>
alignment_for_multiplicative_operator" value="16"/>
keep_anonymous_type_declaration_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_switch_case_expressions" value="insert"/>
wrap_before_shift_operator" value="true"/>
indent_body_declarations_compare_to_annotation_declaration_header" value="true"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_superinterfaces" value="insert"/>
keep_record_declaration_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_before_colon_in_default" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_question_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
brace_position_for_block" value="end_of_line"/>
brace_position_for_constructor_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
brace_position_for_lambda_body" value="end_of_line"/>
number_of_blank_lines_at_end_of_code_block" value="0"/>
compact_else_if" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_catch" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_bitwise_operator" value="insert"/>
put_empty_statement_on_new_line" value="true"/>
alignment_for_parameters_in_constructor_declaration" value="16"/>
alignment_for_type_parameters" value="0"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_method_invocation_arguments" value="insert"/>
alignment_for_arguments_in_method_invocation" value="16"/>
alignment_for_throws_clause_in_constructor_declaration" value="16"/>
alignment_for_compact_loops" value="16"/>
comment.clear_blank_lines_in_block_comment" value="false"/>
insert_new_line_before_catch_in_try_statement" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_try" value="insert"/>
keep_simple_for_body_on_same_line" value="false"/>
insert_new_line_at_end_of_file_if_missing" value="do not insert"/>
comment.clear_blank_lines_in_javadoc_comment" value="false"/>
alignment_for_relational_operator" value="0"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_unary_operator" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_expressions_in_array_initializer" value="16"/>
format_line_comment_starting_on_first_column" value="false"/>
number_of_empty_lines_to_preserve" value="1"/>
parentheses_positions_in_annotation" value="common_lines"/>
insert_space_after_colon_in_case" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_ellipsis" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_additive_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_semicolon_in_try_resources" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_colon_in_assert" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_if" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_and_in_type_parameter" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_string_concatenation" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_parenthesized_expression" value="do not insert"/>
comment.format_line_comments" value="true"/>
brace_position_for_record_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
insert_space_after_colon_in_labeled_statement" value="insert"/>
text_block_indentation" value="0"/>
align_type_members_on_columns" value="false"/>
alignment_for_assignment" value="0"/>
alignment_for_module_statements" value="16"/>
indent_body_declarations_compare_to_type_header" value="true"/>
insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
number_of_blank_lines_after_code_block" value="0"/>
comment.align_tags_names_descriptions" value="false"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_superinterfaces_in_type_declaration" value="16"/>
keep_if_then_body_block_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
blank_lines_before_first_class_body_declaration" value="0"/>
alignment_for_conditional_expression" value="52"/>
insert_new_line_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_constructor_declaration_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
format_guardian_clause_on_one_line" value="false"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_if" value="insert"/>
align_assignment_statements_on_columns" value="false"/>
insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_type" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_block" value="insert"/>
brace_position_for_enum_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
brace_position_for_block_in_case" value="end_of_line"/>
insert_space_before_arrow_in_switch_default" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
comment.insert_new_line_between_different_tags" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_conditional_expression_chain" value="0"/>
comment.format_header" value="false"/>
alignment_for_arguments_in_allocation_expression" value="16"/>
insert_space_before_additive_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_while" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_switch" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_method_declaration" value="0"/>
join_wrapped_lines" value="true"/>
insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
wrap_before_conditional_operator" value="true"/>
indent_switchstatements_compare_to_cases" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_closing_bracket_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_synchronized" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_shift_operator" value="0"/>
align_fields_grouping_blank_lines" value="2147483647"/>
comment.new_lines_at_javadoc_boundaries" value="true"/>
alignment_for_bitwise_operator" value="16"/>
brace_position_for_annotation_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
insert_space_before_colon_in_for" value="insert"/>
alignment_for_resources_in_try" value="80"/>
use_tabs_only_for_leading_indentations" value="false"/>
parentheses_positions_in_try_clause" value="common_lines"/>
alignment_for_selector_in_method_invocation" value="16"/>
never_indent_block_comments_on_first_column" value="false"/>
keep_code_block_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_synchronized" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_constructor_declaration_throws" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_record_components" value="insert"/>
tabulation.size" value="4"/>
insert_space_after_bitwise_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_allocation_expression" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_bracket_in_array_reference" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_colon_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
comment.format_source_code" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_try" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_semicolon_in_try_resources" value="insert"/>
blank_lines_before_field" value="0"/>
insert_space_after_at_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
continuation_indentation_for_array_initializer" value="2"/>
insert_space_after_question_in_wildcard" value="do not insert"/>
blank_lines_before_method" value="1"/>
alignment_for_superclass_in_type_declaration" value="16"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_record_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_superinterfaces_in_enum_declaration" value="16"/>
insert_space_before_parenthesized_expression_in_throw" value="insert"/>
wrap_before_assignment_operator" value="false"/>
insert_space_before_colon_in_labeled_statement" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_not_operator" value="do not insert"/>
brace_position_for_switch" value="end_of_line"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_superinterfaces" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_method_declaration_parameters" value="insert"/>
insert_new_line_after_type_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_parenthesized_expression" value="do not insert"/>
comment.format_html" value="true"/>
insert_space_after_at_in_annotation_type_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_method_delcaration" value="common_lines"/>
alignment_for_compact_if" value="16"/>
keep_lambda_body_block_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
indent_empty_lines" value="false"/>
alignment_for_type_arguments" value="0"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_unary_operator" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_arguments_in_annotation" value="0"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_enum_declarations" value="do not insert"/>
keep_record_constructor_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_record_declaration" value="insert"/>
keep_empty_array_initializer_on_one_line" value="false"/>
indent_switchstatements_compare_to_switch" value="false"/>
insert_new_line_before_else_in_if_statement" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_assignment_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
blank_lines_before_new_chunk" value="1"/>
insert_new_line_after_label" value="do not insert"/>
indent_body_declarations_compare_to_enum_declaration_header" value="true"/>
insert_space_after_opening_bracket_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_colon_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_method_declaration_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_cast" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_arrow_in_switch_case" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_colon_in_assert" value="insert"/>
blank_lines_before_member_type" value="1"/>
insert_new_line_before_while_in_do_statement" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_logical_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_bracket_in_array_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
indent_body_declarations_compare_to_record_header" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_closing_angle_bracket_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_arguments_in_qualified_allocation_expression" value="16"/>
alignment_for_superinterfaces_in_record_declaration" value="16"/>
insert_new_line_after_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
indent_breaks_compare_to_cases" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
wrap_before_bitwise_operator" value="true"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_if" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_semicolon" value="do not insert"/>
wrap_before_relational_operator" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_postfix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_try" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_cast" value="do not insert"/>
comment.format_block_comments" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_lambda_arrow" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
comment.indent_tag_description" value="false"/>
keep_imple_if_on_one_line" value="false"/>
brace_position_for_record_constructor" value="end_of_line"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_enum_declaration" value="insert"/>
alignment_for_parameters_in_method_declaration" value="16"/>
insert_space_between_brackets_in_array_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_string_concatenation" value="16"/>
insert_space_before_semicolon_in_for" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_method_declaration_throws" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_bracket_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
blank_lines_after_last_class_body_declaration" value="0"/>
indent_statements_compare_to_body" value="true"/>
alignment_for_multiple_fields" value="16"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_enum_constant_arguments" value="insert"/>
keep_simple_while_body_on_same_line" value="false"/>
insert_space_before_prefix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
brace_position_for_array_initializer" value="end_of_line"/>
wrap_before_logical_operator" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_shift_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_method_declaration" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_type_parameters" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_catch" value="do not insert"/>
blank_lines_between_statement_group_in_switch" value="0"/>
insert_space_before_closing_bracket_in_array_reference" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_comma_in_annotation" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_enum_constant_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
parentheses_positions_in_lambda_declaration" value="common_lines"/>
insert_space_after_shift_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_between_empty_braces_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_colon_in_case" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_multiple_local_declarations" value="do not insert"/>
keep_simple_do_while_body_on_same_line" value="false"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_annotation_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_bracket_in_array_reference" value="do not insert"/>
keep_enum_declaration_on_one_line" value="one_line_never"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_record_components" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
wrap_outer_expressions_when_nested" value="true"/>
insert_space_after_closing_paren_in_cast" value="insert"/>
brace_position_for_enum_constant" value="end_of_line"/>
brace_position_for_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
insert_space_before_multiplicative_operator" value="insert"/>
blank_lines_before_package" value="0"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_for" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_synchronized" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_for_increments" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_annotation_type_member_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
alignment_for_expressions_in_for_loop_header" value="0"/>
wrap_before_additive_operator" value="true"/>
keep_simple_getter_setter_on_one_line" value="false"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_while" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_explicitconstructorcall_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_after_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
indent_body_declarations_compare_to_enum_constant_header" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_string_concatenation" value="insert"/>
insert_space_after_lambda_arrow" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_constructor_declaration" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_constructor_declaration_throws" value="do not insert"/>
join_lines_in_comments" value="true"/>
insert_space_before_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_question_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
comment.indent_parameter_description" value="false"/>
number_of_blank_lines_at_beginning_of_code_block" value="0"/>
insert_new_line_before_finally_in_try_statement" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_record_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
tabulation.char" value="space"/>
insert_space_after_relational_operator" value="insert"/>
insert_space_before_comma_in_multiple_field_declarations" value="do not insert"/>
wrap_before_string_concatenation" value="true"/>
blank_lines_between_import_groups" value="1"/>
lineSplit" value="140"/>
insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_switch" value="insert"/>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, other formatter settings will matter here as well. Will the code displayed in the _Preview_ area of the formatter profile dialog be formatted differently in the Java editor? By the way, Eclipse 2020-06 is outdated. Please upgrade.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with a fresh 2020-06 Eclipse, but had no luck so far. Can you please share your formatter profile?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a bug, open since July 2019:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549606

> All expressions after a ternary expression that is not contained
> inside of a compound statement, indent at the same indentation level
> as the ternary expression, rather than at the outer block indentation
> level.

The only comment on the issue is that they couldn't reproduce the issue. So my advice is to go to that thread and post your example code, and any other information that might help reproducing the bug.

If I understand this correctly, you should be able to get around this by placing the offending ternary expression in a block (not nice but a workaround):

```
{
 boolean b = a ? b : c;
}

otherStuff();
```

Comment: It has been reported as bug (without attaching the formatter profile), but the status is still _NEW_ and not _ASSIGNED_ (because an instruction to reproduce it is missing), so it's not a bug. I tried to reproduce it, but it works as expected. Maybe the bug was fixed or caused by an installed plugin. Can you reproduce it? And by the way, the mentioned bug report is about something different than the question is about.

Comment: @howlger Not really? I see the same behavior that is mentioned in the bug report (wrong indentation after a ternary expression in the same block) in the second screenshot and that's what OP mentioned in the second half of the question? I agree I didn't mention the double indentation. "So it's not a bug" suuuuure. Ok you know what I am going to try to reproduce it. I note though that OP says it's "seemingly random".

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. You are right, the question is probably about the same issue that has been reported as the mentioned bug (wrong indention after and not inside of the ternary/conditional expression). So thanks for referring to the bug. Unfortunately, it's still unclear how the issue can be reproduced. Maybe you can help by comment to the bug.

Comment: To reproduce, change the formatter option "Line wrapping -> Wrapping settings -> other expressions -> Conditionals" to "Wrap all elements, all elements on a new line". Enter the code from my screen shot and (for me) autosave. I have auto-format in my autosave options.

Comment: @TedTrippin Can you export your full formatter profile and make it available? I am still getting nothing. Also, just to be sure, the code didn't have syntax errors? Because that would mess up the formatter. Oh, and please check what JDT version is installed.

Comment: I've added to the post. Note, I removed `<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter` from each setting so the post was under the length limit.